# Viewing the PDF file in heroku app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ruby, pdf, heroku

I am making a Angular/Rails app which will convert html to PDF.
I deployed my app to Heroku and ran the ruby script to generate PDF files. I see that PDF files are being generated using Heroku's bash.

However, I cannot figure out how to view the file. The pdfs are at `root/lib/pdf/filename.pdf`.

I tried accessing `herokuappname.herokuapp.com/lib/pdf/filename.pdf` but it seems like it is not working this way.

How can I view the content of PDF file in heroku app?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Heroku has an [ephemeral filesystem](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem). So you won't be able to write the pdf files to `/lib` only `/tmp` is temporarily writable but it isn't visible across dynos which may happen if you generate the files in a separate web, worker, or one-off dyno.

What you should do is upload the pdf to a storage service such as Amazon S3 with an upload library such as [paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) and then link to that uploaded file's S3 url when you want to view it.